# Access Database corrupted?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a be database living on a network drive with 10-20 users on front ends at any one time. Lately we have been getting a lot of weird errors.

After some research it seems one table in particular on the be is corrupted. I've tried "Compact and Repair", it just freezes. Tried selecting/deleting the records which read "#Error" and I get a "Not a Valid Bookmark" error, hit ok, "Not a valid bookmark. This cycle repeats 10 to 12 times then stops.

[image]

At the moment I can't export the data. Access freezes.

The "#ERROR" field has taken over maybe 3-5% of the database.

How can I salvage as much of my data as possible and prevent this from happening again?

Is there something I can use in SQL or VBA to delete the corrupt records?

Comment: This would probably be a good place to start: http://allenbrowne.com/ser-47.html

Comment: Also look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646793/maximum-concurrent-connections-in-ms-access

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have that error on local tables yet, but I would try the following:

1. Be sure nobody is currently working in that database (there should be no .laccdb file in the database folder)
2. copy the database file. This is only to make sure things won't get worse.
3. use the Start > Run... window to open the database with the parameter "/decompile" (For example `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 2007\Office12\MSACCESS.EXE" "C:\access\yourDB.accdb" /decompile`)
4. Use "Compact and Repair" again.

If it still doesn't work, create a new database and import the tables of your database. If that doesn't work, too, I don't have an idea how to save your tables. Hope you made a recent backup of your db.

Answer (score 0):

The #Error error value means that Access cannot evaluate an expression. For example, you may have supplied incorrect or too few arguments for an aggregate (totals) function, you may have used a parameter query as the domain for an aggregate function, or you may have made a circular reference in the expression.

You can also check this reference: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/71906/ms-access-mdb-ldb-database-corrupted