# Allow many user access a single database simultaneously without locking

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access, webforms

Using ASP.NET (WebForm), how do I avoid MS Access to lock when more than one user trying to access it at same time? I know MS Access is not optimal for for that purpose but whats the way around it? I assume I've to make some sort of queue, but how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646793/maximum-concurrent-connections-in-ms-access

Answer (score 1):

MS Access is definitely not optimal for that.

Not sure what you´re trying to do exactly but MS Access is locking a file if its opened multiple times from different users. You´d need to make sure that the system user accessing the file is always the same (eg your IIS User maybe) or write a small wrapper that handles the access.

You´d still be only able to do one request at a time so yes you´d need a queue to make that work.

However i´d strongly suggest using SQL for that, maybe try SQL Express as its free and its way easier to use on top.

Comment: I'm aware of that. Do you know any good guide/tutorial for making a queue for this purpose?